# How can I move a Facebook album on my account to a page I created?

Tags: facebook, album

How can I move a Facebook album on my account to a page I created?

I uploaded some images and they have been tagged and commented. I've decided to make a Facebook Page for the group and would like to move the albums from my account to that page without losing the tags or comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible within the Facebook Photos feature.

Answer (score 1):

You could chose to 'Share' the album to your group page (page you manage).

Go to Photos on your main page.
Select Albums
Open the album you would like to share.
Got to the end of the album and click on 'share'.
Choose 'Share on a page you manage'.
Click on 'Post'.